# How do I insert new-line character into Addin Extension Description?

Tags: arcmap, add-in, extensions

Apparently the text box in Esri's Extension manager doesn't wrap text (10.0 SP2).

[image]

As a workaround, I'm trying to insert newline characters into the xml file, but haven't found anything that works.

Here's the xml:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension id="AmberGIS_ExtensionMgrAddin_ExtMgrExtension" class="ExtMgrExtension" productName="Extension State Manager" showInExtensionDialog="true" autoLoad="true">
    <Description>Lets you specify extensions that will be \n turned off automatically when document closes.</Description>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

**Does anyone know how to put a newline character into the add-in xml config file?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I should have searched SO first, I would have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004386/how-to-save-newlines-in-xml-attribute/2004397#2004397).

This seems to work:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension id="AmberGIS_ExtensionMgrAddin_ExtMgrExtension" class="ExtMgrExtension" productName="Extension State Manager" showInExtensionDialog="true" autoLoad="true">
    <Description>Lets you specify extensions that will be &#13;&#10; turned off automatically when document closes.</Description>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Comment: Shame on you Kirk!!!

Comment: Kirk to the rescue! Glad I found this thread it was driving me nuts not getting the text to wrap onto a new line.

Answer (score 1):

The extension description can also be set as a public property and coded directly using:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IExtensionConfig.Description
```

I've found this useful for linking the description to ongoing updates (e.g. new versions) so that I don't have to go back and edit it each time.

EDIT: Note - this will not work for the new add-ins, which must be edited within the XML metadata.

Comment: Does that work with add-in extensions too?  I don't see anything I can override in  [ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Extension_Members/001v000001p9000000/)

Comment: After reading this: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w2000000 it appears that for the new add-ins you have to manage this type of this using the XML. Good to know - I have to port some older extensions over to add-ins soon.